# Minimax algorithm AI not picking the correct choice

Tags: artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, minimax, godot

I have tried to impliment the **minimax algorithm** with alpha/beta pruning for a TicTacToe game I'm making in the Godot Engine, however, it doesn't seem to work as expected. The AI seems to always pick the next available spot on the board from left to right. Can anyone let me know where I might have gone wrong?

Here's my code:

```gdscript
func winner_score() -> int:
    # 0 is X, 1 is Y
    if board.won(0)[0]: return -10
    elif board.won(1)[0]: return 10
    else: return 0

func minimax(_board, _depth: int, alpha, beta, maximizingPlayer: bool):
    var result = winner_score()
    if _depth == 0 or result != 0:
        return result

    if maximizingPlayer:
        var maxEval: int = -100
        for row in range(board.size):
            for col in range(board.size):
                var square = _board[row][col]
                if square.type == null:
                    square.type = HUMAN
                    var eval: int = minimax(_board, _depth - 1, alpha, beta, false)
                    square.type = null
                    maxEval = max(maxEval, eval)
                    alpha = max(alpha, eval)
                    if beta <= alpha: break
        return maxEval

    else:
        var minEval = 100
        for row in range(board.size):
            for col in range(board.size):
                var square = _board[row][col]
                if square.type == null:
                    square.type = AI
                    var eval: int = minimax(_board, _depth - 1, alpha, beta, true)
                    square.type = null          
                    minEval = min(minEval, eval)
                    beta = min(beta, eval)
                    if beta <= alpha: break
        return minEval
```